# Problem connecting testrpc to remix

Tags: remix, testrpc

Whenever I try to use a Web3 Provider on Remix it says

`Not possible to connect to the Web3 provider. Make sure the provider is running and a connection is open (via IPC or RPC).`

I have testrpc running, is there anything else required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error may be caused by Remix run from *http**s*** (https://remix.ethereum.org). If so, it should be fixed by switching to http (i.e. http://remix.ethereum.org)