# How to connect these **Remix - kovan - parity**?

Tags: parity, remix, kovan, web3-providers

I have been trying to connect deploy a smart contract from remix onto kovan chain via parity but kept on showing even after trying with all the rpc flags.
if possible please throughly explain the procedure and theory behind it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, the Remix site is from HTTPS. So chances are it's the same problem as in this question: [Problem connecting testrpc to remix](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29584/problem-connecting-testrpc-to-remix?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: no i have tried that also it still not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose

https://monosnap.com/file/5j4jjOzjZT1QGU7rDKs3MH75YRvrO0
Web3 Provider Kovan 42 
and be sure your parity script is running and connect to chain

```
parity --peers 5 --chain testnet -l own_tx=trace
```